# ANTLR4 dynamic token type

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

The language that I am lexing requires the ability to hot-swap keywords depending on runtime configuration.

It's relatively simple how to do this so long as you are OK embedding target-specific code in your grammar (Java):<sup>1</sup>

```java
lexer grammar LanguageLexer;

tokens {
If, Else, While // etc
}

@header {
import java.util.Map;
}

@members {
private Map<String, Integer> keywords;
public NafiLexer(CharStream input, Map<String, Integer> keywords) {
    this(input);
    this.keywords = keywords;
}
}

WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;
ID: [a-zA-Z]+ { if(keywords.containsKey(getText())) setType(keywords.get(getText())); };
```

However, I would like to remove all target-specific code from my `.g4` file, as my `.g4`s will be used across multiple target languages for separate projects.

In a `Parser`, you can use a `Listener` to remove embedded actions and decouple the grammar from application-specific code. However, if there exists a way to do this at the Lexer level<sup>2</sup>, I have yet to find it (thus asking this question).

The way to accomplish this seems to be to wrap the `TokenStream` pulled from the `Lexer`. This wrapping `TokenStream` would read `Token`s as they were provided, and apply the transformation currently in an embedded action to any `ID` tokens present.

This (in theory) would not be difficult to implement; however, this feels like functionality that should be possible with just the already defined ANTLR symbols. So, the question is: **is it possible to conditionally change the type of tokens passing through a `TokenStream` within the existing ANTLR system?** If not, what is the lowest-friction way of accomplishing that task? An example using the Java library would be preferred, as that is the one I am most familiar with.

And as a sub-question: if I end up creating a `TokenTransformationStream` for my required targets, would it be worth suggesting adding it to the existing libraries? (I can create symbols for all current supplied targets.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, this will crash if you construct a Lexer with the regular constructor. In a real application, it might be worth fixing that, but for this example, it doesn't matter.

<sup>2</sup> I feel this is an appropriate task for the lexer level for a couple reasons. The main reason is that it seems common practice to pass keywords as keyword tokens always, and then, if necessary, allow them as identifiers at the parser level (such as context-sensitive keywords). Also, other questions asking simply *how* to achieve this effect suggest a method basically equivalent to the above provided embedded actions solution.

Comment: The most promising symbol I can find for this task is `org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStreamRewriter`, but if I'm reading its javadoc correctly, it's only for changing the text representation.

Comment: Could you somehow know this `runtime configuration` before the lexing/parsing starts?

Comment: @cantSleepNow Yes, it's known before and constant at each runtime.

Comment: Could you use lexer modes? Because in combo with that you could then set types without language specific code.

Comment: @cantSleepNow I don't see any reason I can't, but I also don't see how modes would help in this case. Please add an answer if you think modes solve the question

Comment: @CAD97 did you ever solve this? I have a use-case very similar to yours. I have it working by simply iterating over the tokens between the lexing and parsing stages, carrying out the check and manually swapping the type where necessary. The key thing here is that I call `.fill()` on the CommonTokenStream to get _all_ the tokens from the lexer and then carry out the hot-swapping _before_ attaching and running the parser. Another approach I've considered (but not yet tried) would be to use a TokenFactory to be able to carry out this check (and modify the type) during the creation of the Token.

Answer (score 0):

This may not turn out to be the answer to the question, but it's simply too long for comment.
I meant lexer modes in the comments because I was focused on this part `hot-swap keywords`. I don't know why you need to change the token type, but if you use lexer modes maybe you will not care about it.

The only catch is there need to be some keywords which indicate changing of the lexer mode. Basically one lexer mode would be a sub-lexer grammar (of sorts.)

```
RUNTIME_CFG_! : 'runtime_cfg_1' -> mode(m_CGF_1);
...
mode m_CGF_1;
KEYWORD1 : 'key1;
...
```

If there are some same keywords you can also use lexer function `type`* to explicitly set the type of the token.

*I can't remember in the moment how it's called but by lexer function I mean one of those like `mode`, `skip` etc..